# Sublime Text: cursor move to end of long list/dictionary

Tags: sublimetext3

For example there are very long list or dictionary in the code, that I need to flip pages to reach the end of the list or dictionary.

What's the convenient way that I can reach the end of the list or dictionary, instead of manually times of "Page Down"?

```
the_list = [
"Liam",
"Noah",
...
...
...
"Oliver"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using the `Goto` menu -> `Jump to Matching Bracket` <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> by default.
When inside brackets, it jumps to the end/close bracket. When at the end bracket it jumps to the begin/open bracket.